# JavaScript glitch (probably simple, too) in need of solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a JavaScript applied to two images.  The video can be seen here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYc8swGK5Lw
The first image I hover over in the video acts properly, however, the second does not.  The second picture appears to apply the margin-top immediately after the hover, instead of transition like the first one.  This causes the browser to get confused and mouse-over and out once or twice before stability is restored.  Both pictures have the gallery_left class applied to them, but the first picture hovered over in the video has the left4 ID applied to it.  The second picture hovered over in the video has the left7 ID applied to it.  Finally, here's the code.

```
$(function() {
var margin_top;
$('img.gallery_left').mouseover(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == "left4") {
        margin_top = '105px';
    } else {
        $(this).css('marginTop');
    }
    if($(this).attr('id') == "left7") {
        margin_top = '353px';
    } else {
        $(this).css('marginTop');
    }

    $(this).animate({
        borderWidth: '10px',
        width: '750px',
        height: '500px',
        marginLeft: '1px',
        zIndex: '15',
        marginTop: margin_top,
    }, 
    'default');
});

$('img.gallery_left').mouseout(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == "left4") {
        margin_top = '261px';
    } else {
        $(this).css('marginTop');
    }
    if($(this).attr('id') == "left7") {
        margin_top = '511px';
    } else {
        $(this).css('marginTop');
    }

    $(this).animate({
        borderWidth: '4px',
        width: '300px',
        height: '200px',
        marginLeft: '1px',
        zIndex: '0',
        marginTop: margin_top,
    }, 
    'default');
});
});
```

I have to apply the code to all of the other pictures as well, but for starters I'm just doing it to those two pictures.  Please help me out and try to identify the issue with this code.

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot this without seeing the HTML...the same Javascript functions are being applied to both images, so theoretically the timing of changing the margins should be the same for both, even though the actual margin values are different.

Comment: @MattB. The code is literally like this: <img class="gallery_left" id="left1" src="assets/community/fall_regionals/img01.png" />
        <img class="gallery_center" id="center2" src="assets/community/fall_regionals/img02.png" />
         <img class="gallery_right" id="right3" src="assets/community/fall_regionals/img03.png" />
        <img class="gallery_left" id="left4" src="assets/community/fall_regionals/img04.png" />
         <img class="gallery_center" id="center5" src="assets/community/fall_regionals/img05.png" /> etc.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
        $(this).css('marginTop');
```

does nothing.  You probably meant something like this:

```
if(this.id == "left4") {
    margin_top = '261px';
} else if ( this.id == "left7") {
    margin_top = '511px';
} else {
    margin_top = $(this).css('marginTop');
}
```

That way you are storing the css property.  Also, you only need one if/else series so you don't overwrite the `if` of the first series with the `else` of the second.

Comment: Doesn't change the result that happened in the video.

Comment: Did you make sure to clear your cache?  Also, make sure you change both the mouseover/mouseout `if` statements.  Can you make a jsFiddle rather than making a completely non-interactive video?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the if: I think it should be something like

```
if($(this).attr('id') == "left4") {
    margin_top = '105px';
} else if($(this).attr('id') == "left7") {
    margin_top = '353px';
} else {
    margin_top = $(this).css('marginTop');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first image you're not actually changing the `margin-top` at all (at no point in your code do you change the `margin-top` for the image with ID `left1`). As @Dennis pointed out, `$(this).css('marginTop');` does nothing. So in fact your `margin-top` code is problematic across the board, not just with the second image - it's just that you're not actually changing anything with the first image, making it appear to work correctly (I'm guessing you expected the first image to have a `margin-top` of zero?).

I think the issue might be that you're passing 'default' as the second parameter to `$.animate`. I looked over the documentation for `$.animate` and I don't see 'default' mentioned anywhere as a valid option for that parameter (the `duration` parameter). Instead, try setting it to `fast`, `slow`, or some numeric value.